# Python 3.5.0 :::: Instalar pygame

Tags: python-3.x

Já tentei instalar o pygame no python IDLE usando pip mas não funcionou, no entanto encontrei um download que me instalou uma pasta com o pygame pronto a instalar no meu local drive. Quando instalei o pygame e abri o python fiz: import pygame, mas ao executar o módulo diz que não existe módulo 'pygame'.

```
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ImportError: No module named 'pygame'
>>>
```

Sabem como o instalar? Como é que resolvo este problema?

*Eu uso python 3.5.0 e Windows 10 pro*

Comment: que sistema operacional você usa?

Comment: Windows 10 pro.

Comment: por isso que o pip não deu certo. 
desculpe, não sei te ajudar, eu saberia se usa-se linux.

Comment: é recomendado que tente em um virtual machine o mesmo! pois o windows 10 ainda tem muito pouco recursos, já que o mesmo foi lançado em setembro.

Comment: A solução está nesse link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ki_5uS4bOgQ
:-)

Answer (score 5):

Observação: Escrevi esta resposta aqui no Stack Overflow, mas não consegui enviar os links na mensagem (o site diz que não tenho "reputação" para indicar mais de 2 links por mensagem).  Por isso, deixei esta mesma mensagem em formato TXT, com os links necessários, no seguinte endereço:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B88rg0vKkrOFdmdKMmx0TEk5SHc/view?usp=sharing

---

Olá!

Eu tenho o Windows 10 de 64 bits, e consegui fazer o Python e Pygame funcionarem, do seguinte modo:

1) Entrei no site do Python (ver TXT do link acima), e baixei o Python 3.5.1 (de 07/12/2015), e instalei.

Se não me engano, durante a instalação cliquei na opção de instalação customizada, e selecionei a opção de "para todos os usuários", alterar variáveis de ambiente, e deixei a pasta padrão, que no meu caso foi 
"C:\Program Files\Python35".  Se você não entrar na instalação customizada, eu acho que mais tarde terá que acrescentar o caminho (pastas) do Python manualmente, na variável de ambiente "PATH" do Windows.

Apenas informando: No prompt de comando (CMD), ao digitar o comando PATH, notei que o instalador acrescentou as seguintes pastas, logo no início do path:

C:\Program Files\Python35\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python35\;

2) Entrei no site do PyGame (ver TXT do link acima) e selecionei a versão do PyGame correspondente à versão do Python que mencionei no item 1.
A versão que baixei foi esta:

pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl

Obs.: Até onde consegui descobrir, no nome do arquivo, o "cp35" significa que é a versão 3.5 do PyGame, e o "amd64" significa que é a versão de 64 bits.

3) Assisti ao vídeo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdGoAnFP-mU, e segui as instrução dele.

- O vídeo trata de versões mais antigas do Python 3.4.1 e do PyGame, mas com as versões mais recentes que mencionei nos itens 1 e 2, deu certo.
- O autor do vídeo vai pedir para entrar em certos endereços, clicar em certos menus, etc.  Porém, nesta parte, basta você entrar nos dois links a que me referi acima, e chegará diretamente aos arquivos necessários.
- A parte que você terá que seguir rigorosamente é a partir de quando ele trata da renomeação do arquivo .whl para .zip, copiar arquivos para dentro da pasta do Python, etc.
- Lembre-se de adaptar as pastas mencionadas no vídeo, para a SUA pasta do Python.
- No meu caso, onde o vídeo menciona a pasta "C:\PythonXX", eu usei a pasta "C:\Program Files\Python35", que foi onde eu instalei o Python (assumindo, como já disse, a pasta padrão do instalador).
- Outro cuidado a tomar é que, nas instruções escritas no vídeo, é feita referência a uma pasta chamada "pygame-1.9.2a0.dist-info" mas, poucos minutos depois, o autor do vídeo corrigiu para "pygame-1.9.2a0.data".
  Chamo a atenção para este detalhe porque, se você decidir parar o vídeo no início das instruções e segui-las do jeito que lá estão, não saberá que, mais à frente, o nome dessa pasta foi corrigido.
  Assim, sugiro que você realmente vá executando as instruções conforme for assistindo ao vídeo, sem pular ou tentar antecipar nada.

4) Talvez você prefira instalar o Python em alguma outra pasta de sua preferência (C:\Python35, por exemplo), e eu SUPONHO que isso deveria funcionar.
Porém, quaisquer que sejam os programas que instalo, tenho por hábito sempre aceitar a pasta padrão dos instaladores, justamente para não correr o risco de me deparar com algum erro chato, por causa de algum problema do instalador.

Se você for arriscar instalar o Python em outra pasta que não a "padrão" do instalador, e no caso de não dar certo o funcionamento do PyGame, sugiro que DESINSTALE (pelo painel de controle do Windows) a versão que instalou, e tente resinstalar, desta vez usando a pasta padrão.

5) Infelizmente, se estas instruções não funcionarem para você, não terei muito mais a dizer, pois sou iniciante no Python e no PyGame.

Boa sorte!
Paulo

Answer (score 2):

Está a acontecer que o python não está a conseguir localizar a instalação dessa biblioteca. Isto pode acontecer porque, por exemplo:

- a biblioteca não foi instalada num directório onde o python esteja a procurar bibliotecas;
- na instalação, a directoria correspondente não foi adicionada à variável do sistema `PATH`.

Não uso Windows, por isso não poderei dar instruções em como fazer isso, mas sei que dá para fazer para cada sessão do cmd ou para todo o sistema.

Uma abordagem alternativa é fazer isso directamente na execução do script, por exemplo:

```py
import os
import sys

pygame_dir = 'inserir aqui o directório completo para a pasta do pygame'
sys.path.append(pygame_dir)

import pygame
```

Answer (score 1):

Existe um caminho bem simples:
baixe o python;
baixe a pygame adequada a versão do python instalado;
copia o arquivo pygame baixado para a pasta Scripts na instalação do python;
abra o prompt na pasta scripts como administrador (shift + botão direito mouse);
execute o comando:  pip install NOME_COMPLETO_DO_ARQUIVO_COM_EXTENSÃO e da enter;
pronto.
Boa sorte...